# How to Make Brand name on product page- clickable using shortcodes, plugin- Brands for woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode

I am using flatsome theme and have to design custom product page. I am using Brands for Woocommerce plugin. I got the Brand name above the Title through [product_brands_info type=’name’]. But I want it to be clickable so that it should redirect to the specific brand page. Pls help
http://artpoint.edupox.com/product/untitled-4/

Answer (score 0):

I have checked the plugin and seems there is no options for linking with this shortcode but in this shortcode you can easily add codes using these two actions. These actions will work before and after the shortcodes content.

Add these codes in your activated theme's functions.php file. If you want you can also add `target="_blank"` in the `<a>` tag as it is an external link.

```
add_action('product_brands_info_before', 'add_brand_link_start');
function add_brand_link_start($term){
    $brand_url  = get_term_meta( $term->term_id, 'br_brand_url', true );
    ?>
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url($brand_url); ?>">
    <?php
}

add_action('product_brands_info_after', 'add_brand_link_end');
function add_brand_link_end($term){
    ?>
    </a>
    <?php
}
```

Make sure you have added brand url in the admin panel, please see the screenshot https://prnt.sc/_YaUhdokAQCd . Hope it will work for you.

Comment: After doing the above,when the brand name is clicked, link refreshes the same product page.The link does not go to brand page. Am i doing something wrong? Kindly help

Comment: Could you please confirm that you have put a url in the admin panel, because I can see in your site that the url is empty https://prnt.sc/PualoPbLbSkc .  You need to put a url in the admin area here https://prnt.sc/_YaUhdokAQCd .

Comment: It is working. I had forgotten to put the url. I cannot thank you enough. Keep up the good work of guiding newbies like me. Thanks again

Comment: There is a slight problem with the code. Alongwith Brand name, everything else has become 'clickable', including product attributes and brand description. can you help me solve it?

Comment: Well, in this case what you can do to add only the first hook and add your link there like <a href="<?php echo esc_url($brand_url); ?>"><?php echo esc_html($term->name); ?></a> and then you can hide the bottom's name by adding a line of css. Hope it will work for you. I have checked that the shortcode has no other actions.

Comment: Can you do it for me? i mean freelance. There is some more customization requirements also.